# React Native Server Configuration

Tags: ios, react-native

guys! I'm a student iOS developer and new to the GREAT technique React Native.

My Question is:

- if it is necessary for us to develop our React Native server with the help of Node.js? Can the server just return a static javascript file or bundle file to the client?
- if so, does it mean that every time user enters THE React Native page(contains RCT controller or view), the App do not have to fetch the javascript file or bundle file from server? (Since if these files are unchanged in server, App should not download them for saving phone data/flow)
- if so, could we use some Tag & Cache technique to solve this data saving problem?

Comment: it bundles the JS in the app, nothing is "downloaded"

Comment: While React Native downloads a .jsbundle file over the network for development purposes, this is discouraged for production apps, and when you build your project for launch in the Play Store/App Store, it will bundle this file with the app. So, production apps will not download the budle